# How to calculate the running time of my program?

Tags: java, performance

I wrote a program and now I want to calculate the total running time of my program from start to end.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Use [System.nanoTime](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_nanotime.htm) to get the current time.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
.....your program....
long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(totalTime);
```

The above code prints the running time of the program in nanoseconds.

Comment: long totalTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
System.out.println(totalTime); if working with segs

Comment: This doesn't work if the System clock updates while your app is running.

Answer (score 53):

At the beginning of your main method, add this line of code :

```
final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
```

And then, at the last line of your main method, you can add :

```
final long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

`duration` now contains the time in nanoseconds that your program ran. You can for example print this value like this:

```
System.out.println(duration);
```

If you want to show duration time in seconds, you must divide the value by 1'000'000'000. Or if you want a `Date` object: `Date myTime = new Date(duration / 1000);` You can then access the various methods of `Date` to print number of minutes, hours, etc.

Comment: `long seconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(after - before);`

Answer (score 26):

Use System.[currentTimeMillis](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())() or System.[nanoTime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())() if you want even more precise reading. Usually, milliseconds is precise enough if you need to output the value to the user. Moreover, `System.nanoTime()` *may* return negative values, thus it may be possible that, if you're using that method, the return value is not correct.

A general and wide use would be to use milliseconds :

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

... 


long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
System.out.print("Execution time is " + formatter.format((end - start) / 1000d) + " seconds");
```

Note that nanoseconds are usually used to calculate very short and precise program executions, such as unit testing and benchmarking. Thus, for overall program execution, milliseconds are preferable.

Comment: Beware that System.currentTimeMillis() is affected by changes of the system clock whereas System.nanoTime() isn't. So in case the system clock is set back 5 minutes by NTP the result with System.currentTimeMills() mabye 55 minutes whereas the result with System.nanoTime() may give 60 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

The general approach to this is to:

1. Get the time at the start of your benchmark, say at the start of `main()`.
2. Run your code.
3. Get the time at the end of your benchmark, say at the end of `main()`.
4. Subtract the start time from the end time and convert into appropriate units.

A hint: look at `System.nanoTime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: As an additional note: Since 1.5 you can use java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit for easy conversions from milliseconds and especially nano-seconds to other units.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the time when the application starts, and compare that to the time when the application ends.

Wen the app starts:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// Get start time (this needs to be a global variable).
Date startDate = calendar.getTime();
```

When the application ends

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// Get start time (this needs to be a global variable).
Date endDate = calendar.getTime();
```

To get the difference (in millseconds), do this:

```
long sumDate = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

Comment: using Date and Calendar to obtain a duration in milliseconds seems a little bit "overkill" to me, System.currentTimeMillis() would be a better pick. And if you copy past all your lines in the main method, calendar will be defined two times -> compilation error

Answer (score 2):

Beside the well-known (and already mentioned) `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` there is also a neat library called [perf4j](https://web.archive.org/web/20150506133949/http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) which might be useful too, depending on your purpose of course.

Comment: Good lib, but hasn't been updated since about 8 years.