# How can i check the run time of java program?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, runtime

I need to check if an array is a sub-array of another bigger array.
(find an word(sub-array) in a sentence(array)).

I need to do that in a recursion algorithm.
that the run time will be log(n).

the arrays :

```
        char[] sentence = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
    char[] word = {'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r'};
                char [] word = {'t', 'n' , 'p'};
```

my code:

```
    static boolean wordFinder(char[] arr, char[] arr2, int l, int i) {

    if (i == arr2.length - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (arr[l] == arr2[i]) {
        return wordFinder(arr, arr2, l + 1, i + 1);
    }
    if (l == arr.length - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return wordFinder(arr, arr2, l + 1, 0);


}
```

the third array is only for checking the code.
(the code works, just need to know the run time).

Comment: It is totally unclear for me what is the problem here. What do you mean by "run time"? What does it have to do with those arrays?

Comment: I guess he means **complexity** by "run time".

Comment: @Amongalen i need to check if the second array (char[] word) can be fitted to the first array (char [] sentence). i mean if the sentence is "hello world", and the word is "world". i can fit the word array to the sentence array. implement the word array in the sentence array. and by Run-time I mean . I know there are run time of O(n^2), O(n) , log(n) that symbols the run-time. i want to know what my run time is. O(n) or log(n).

Comment: And you say that your code works so what is the problem?

Comment: These question have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204051/how-to-calculate-the-running-time-of-my-program)

Comment: Are you actually asking that "is your current implementation complexity is O(log(n)) or other?"

Comment: @Amongalen i want to know the run time. O(n) or log(n).

Comment: @ruhul yes. i am a student and my teacher gave me that as a homework.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in testing how long a block of code takes to run. To do that, just record the time before and after in milliseconds, and then subtract the two.

```
long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

...
...

long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Code completed in " + (end_time - start_time) + "milliseconds.");
```

There's also `System.nanoTime()` for nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime complexity of your program is **O(n*m)**. Here n is the length or `arr` and `m` is the length of `arr2`
**why:** because in each recursion, there is actually nested loop in each recursion. One loop to iterate over `arr` and other is to iterate over `arr2` for each element of `arr`.

Well, minimum complexity would be **O(n)**.

Update: Have a look at this link: [check-string-substring-another](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-string-substring-another/)

Comment: thanks :), can you please give me a hint on how to  make it log(n)?

Comment: @Sufferring did you get your answer?

Comment: i saw the link you sent me. and i didn't understand why he runs a loop to create int j if he starts it at 0.plus he runs a for loop inside a for loop. doesnt it makes the run time complexity to o(n^2)?

Comment: You need to check if all the element of `arr2` (j,  0 to length) is equal to the elements of `arr` (current position i to i+j). arr[i] == arr2[j] .. arr[i+1] == arr[j+1]...

Comment: but wouldn't it  make it o(n^2)? because i am running loop inside a loop..

Comment: but i need  log(n). or o(n) (if its the minimum complexity as said).