# Is there a way to calculate the time it takes to find a value in an array for Interpolation Search Algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, structure

I have a code for an Interpolation Search Algorithm seen below. I want to know that if there is an array with values, how to I code it to make it calculate the time it took to find in nanoseconds/milliseconds?

import java.util.*;

class GFG {

```
// If x is present in arr[0..n-1], then returns
// index of it, else returns -1.
public static int interpolationSearch(int arr[], int lo,
                                      int hi, int x)
{
    int pos;

    // Since array is sorted, an element
    // present in array must be in range
    // defined by corner
    if (lo <= hi && x >= arr[lo] && x <= arr[hi]) {

        // Probing the position with keeping
        // uniform distribution in mind.
        pos = lo
              + (((hi - lo) / (arr[hi] - arr[lo]))
                 * (x - arr[lo]));

        // Condition of target found
        if (arr[pos] == x)
            return pos;

        // If x is larger, x is in right sub array
        if (arr[pos] < x)
            return interpolationSearch(arr, pos + 1, hi,
                                       x);

        // If x is smaller, x is in left sub array
        if (arr[pos] > x)
            return interpolationSearch(arr, lo, pos - 1,
                                       x);
    }
    return -1;
}

// Driver Code
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // Array of items on which search will
    // be conducted.
    int arr[] = { 10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21,
                  22, 23, 24, 33, 35, 42, 47 };

    int n = arr.length;

    // Element to be searched
    int x = 18;
    int index = interpolationSearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x);

    // If element was found
    if (index != -1)
        System.out.println("Element found at index "
                           + index);
    else
        System.out.println("Element not found.");
}
```

}

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204051/how-to-calculate-the-running-time-of-my-program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the running time of my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204051/how-to-calculate-the-running-time-of-my-program)